# How to make recursive http calls within an Angular2 service to prefetch data?

Tags: angular, recursion, angular2-services, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I've got an Angular service which fetches records from an open API. The API limits me to fetching 100 records at a time and I won't know how many records there are to fetch until I retrieve the first batch.

The format of the API response looks like this:

```
{
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 100,
    "total": 140,
    "count": 100,
    "results": []
}
```

I don't know how many calls I need to make to the API until after I fetch the first page and get the `"total"` value from the response.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: How does it limit you, if you request 101 does it respond with 100 and then error? Does it just error?

Comment: It responds with http status code 409 and errors out if you provide a limit > 100.

Comment: The component function that calls the fetching service can simply be made to call itself again recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Not angular an specific problem, so no (real) code here.

In any language; you can do something like this:
(i.e call the getData function from the function that receives the data)

```
var limit = 100;
var offset = 0;

function getData(offset) {
 someHTTPcall('http://...?offset='+offset)
 mapData(response)
}

function mapData(result) {
 myData.push(response.results)
 if (myData.length < response.total) {
   getData(myData.lenght +1)
 }
}
```